# Working through examples, I don't see a MyBorder class in Navomatic Example

Tags: wicket

Working through examples, I don't see a MyBorder class in the ["Navomatic" Example](https://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/navomatic.html).  Without this class the example doesn't work, and I don't see (or may have missed) an explanation of what it is, and something indicating where it's defined.  The import line below
`import org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.MyBorder;`
generates a "cannot be resolved" error.

I'm open to suggestions as to how to proceed.

I was expecting this class to either be defined within the example, or for the import to work which references it.  Neither appears to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

The examples' sources could be found [here](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-examples/). In a browser just type `t` to search and enter the name of the class/file in the search box.

And `MyBorder` is [here](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples/compref/MyBorder.java)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  First thing this morning, I found the java and html files for MyBorder on my own, and added them to my navomatic example project.  The project works, but it doesn't draw the borders on the screens.  Am I still missing something?

Comment: You are missing two things: 1) to show us your code; and 2) to accept the answer to your original question